# How to init and insert struct with foreign key constraint into db using GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to create a rest API with golang. Each time a user is created, I would like to create a 'Profile' which is associated with that user.

My initial thought was to first create the user, and then separately create the profile referencing the user ID and inserting that into the database.

I'm not sure if this kind of thinking aligns with the way go should be used as i'm just starting with the language.

Using below code, I create the user, but cannot create the profile. I receive this error: `using unaddressable value`

```
var db *gorm.DB

func GetDB() *gorm.DB {
    return db
}

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Email    string `gorm:"type:varchar(100);unique_index"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    Token    string `json:"token";sql:"-"`
}

type Profile struct {
    gorm.Model
    User        User `gorm:"foreignkey:UserRefer"` // use UserRefer as foreign key
    UserRefer   uint
    FirstName   string `gorm:"default:'John'"`
    LastName    string `gorm:"default:'Doe'"`
    Description string `gorm:"default:'Mysterious'"`
}

func (user *User) Create() (map[string]interface{}) {

    if resp, ok := user.Validate(); !ok {
        return resp
    }

    hashedPassword, _ := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(user.Password), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
    user.Password = string(hashedPassword)

    GetDB().Create(user)

    profile := Profile{}
    profile.UserRefer = user.ID

    GetDB().Create(profile)

    if user.ID <= 0 {
        return u.Message(false, "Failed to create account, connection error.")
    }

    response := u.Message(true, "Account has been created")
    response["user"] = user

    return response

}
```

I'm hoping someone will be able to help me understand what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a pointer on gorm's Create method to get your model Filled after creation...

```golang
GetDB().Create(&profile)
```

But, as is showed in https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html gorm Auto create the associations.

You can change your models, like so... (I am supposing that User and Profile has a 1..1 relation ok?)
And everything will get done automatically

```golang
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Email     string `gorm:"type:varchar(100);unique_index"`
    Password  string `json:"password"`
    Name      string `json:"name"`
    Token     string `json:"token";sql:"-"`
    Profile   Profile
    ProfileID uint
}

type Profile struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserID      uint
    FirstName   string `gorm:"default:'John'"`
    LastName    string `gorm:"default:'Doe'"`
    Description string `gorm:"default:'Mysterious'"`
}
```